# How To Display Product API by categories using laravel

Tags: laravel, api

My expected JSON format:
[image]

This is my expected JSON format, I have a product table along with products related table. I want to show products in categories wise. 
Product Table:
[image]

Category Table:
[image]

Here is my product model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    private $minimum_price;

    /**
     * Get the products image.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrlAttribute()
    {
        if (!empty($this->image)) {
            $image_url = asset('/storage/img/product/' . $this->image);
        } else {
            $image_url = asset('/img/default.png');
        }
        return $image_url;
    }

    public function product_variations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\ProductVariation::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the brand associated with the product.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Brands::class);
    }

     /**
     * Get the unit associated with the product.
     */
    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Unit::class);
    }
    /**
     * Get category associated with the product.
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
    }
    /**
     * Get sub-category associated with the product.
     */
    public function sub_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class, 'sub_category_id', 'id');
    }


    /**
     * Get the brand associated with the product.
     */
    public function product_tax()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\TaxRate::class, 'tax', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the variations associated with the product.
     */
    public function variations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Variation::class);
    }

    /**
     * If product type is modifier get products associated with it.
     */
    public function modifier_products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class, 'res_product_modifier_sets', 'modifier_set_id', 'product_id');
    }

    /**
     * If product type is modifier get products associated with it.
     */
    public function modifier_sets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class, 'res_product_modifier_sets', 'product_id', 'modifier_set_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the purchases associated with the product.
     */
    public function purchase_lines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\PurchaseLine::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class);
    }

    public function attributesWithoutDefault()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class)->where('attribute_id', '>', 4);
    }

    public function vendor_product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VendorProduct::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

    public function origin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductOrigin::class);
    }

    public function defaultAttributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class)->where('attribute_id', '<=', 4);
    }

    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductNote::class);
    }

    public function additionalCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class, 'additional_category', 'id');
    }

    public function getAdditionalCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        $additional_category = $this->additionalCategory;
        return $additional_category ? $additional_category->name : null;
    }

    public function industries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Industry::class, 'product_industries');
    }

    public function getCatalogUrlAttribute()
    {
        return asset('/uploads/'. constants('product_catalog_path') . '/' . $this->catalog_brusher);
    }

    public function getSpecSheetUrlAttribute()
    {
        return asset('/uploads/'. constants('product_spec_sheet_path') . '/' . $this->spec_sheet);
    }

    public function relatedProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'related_products', 'product_id', 'related_product_id');
    }

    private function setMinPrice()
    {
        if (is_null($this->minimum_price)) {
            $this->minimum_price = $this->vendor_product->min('price');
        }
        return $this->minimum_price;
    }

    public function getMinPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->setMinPrice();
    }

    public function getMinPriceVendorAttribute()
    {
        $min_price = $this->setMinPrice();
        if (is_null($min_price)) return null;

        $min_vendor_product = $this->vendor_product->firstWhere('price', $min_price);
        return Contact::find($min_vendor_product->vendor_id);
    }

    /**
     * Get the unit quantity associated with the product.
     */
    public function unitQuantity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\UnitQuantity::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup your relationships already?

Comment: I  set up my relationship ,here is my product model:  public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
    }
    /**
     * Get sub-category associated with the product.
     */
    public function sub_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class, 'sub_category_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of in comment

Comment: @ChristopheHubert   I attached my product model on the question if you need more, please mention me

Comment: @ChristopheHubert  Hello brother basically I want to show my products in categories wise from my product table. for this reason, I need to join with category table but what is the procedure to retrieve data in this case which is related more three categories or less and my expected JSON format upon there.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you should join the same table more than once, every time you join,

you join with suitable alias name:

```
$list = Product::
leftJoin('categories as mainCategory','products.category_id','mainCategory.id')
->leftJoin('categories as subCategory','products.sub_category_id','subCategory.id')
->leftJoin('categories as additionalCategory','products.additional_category','additionalCategory.id')
->select(['products.*','mainCategory.name as mainCategoryName','subCategory.name as subCategoryName','additionalCategory.name as additionalCategoryName'])->get();
```

please note that your column 'products.additional_category' should be named

products.additional_category_id

see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835059/10573560

Comment: Thank you for your response.What you said i tried it but my expected JSON format was given over here.please have a look. Basically, what I want  at first I need to check the category after that if the category exists i need to push the list in categoryDetails then in this list need to check subcategory this way my expected json format ,if you look over there then you can understand what i need.Please suggested me what should i do